# Giving a shadow cause to slowly scroll down

Tags: ios, performance, shadow, quartz-core

I have white background and white label on it, so I need to give a shadow all side of characters I use this code and it works! but it cause to slowly scroll do you have any idea how can solve this problem?

```
cell.L_name.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
cell.L_name.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
cell.L_name.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
cell.L_name.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: In this method:
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting

```
cell.L_name.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

this will render your label as a bitmap and might improve scrolling smoothness

additionally you could set

```
cell.opaque = YES;
```

which will optimize drawing performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `shadowPath` for the layer would probably increase the performance greatly.

```
cell.L_name.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath pathWithRect:L_name.bounds].CGPath;
```

Besides, you can cache the generated shadow as a bitmap, which also increases the performance considerably. Do not forget to set `rasterizationScale` for retina displays.

```
cell.L_name.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.L_name.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Comment: Actually I try to add 
cell.L_name.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath pathWithRect:L_name.bounds].CGPath; but after this code; not only characters all of the label has a shadow :)

Comment: It was a sample, you have to set the path you desire. If you want the characters in a label to have shadow rather than the label itself, you have to create a path along the edges of the characters.